# Jquery. If a url in certain div contains something, then something

Tags: jquery

Trying to set up an alert window pop up for certain links via jquery.
My code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = a.link_imagelibrary 
if ("url:contains ('#hidden')") {
    $("url").click(function(){
  alert("yes!");
});
}
});
```

What where is my mistake?

Comment: There is no meaning for this `"url:contains ('#hidden')"`. See the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you are trying to do is to find links with a class of "link_imagelibrary" and if their `href` property contains the string "#hidden", bind a click handler to them.

If that is correct, then the following code will do that:

```
$('a.link_imagelibrary[href*=#hidden]').click(function () {
    alert('yes!');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter through all the anchor tags with class `link_imagelibrary` and the assign the click event to the resulting set.

```
$("a.link_imagelibrary").filter(function(){
 return this.href.indexOf("#hidden") > -1;
}).click(function(){
 alert("yes!");
});
```

Comment: This is functionally identical to my answer, though more verbose. I wonder is one is more performant that the other?

Comment: @GregL - Ah, a kindred spirit haha. I wondered the same thing myself and made a jsperf for it: http://jsperf.com/filter-versus-css-selector

Comment: Interesting! I tried to do a [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-attribute-contains-selector-vs-filter-callback) myself and got the opposite result to you (though yours is closer to the situation the OP had). I wonder what accounts for the different results? Is it that the selector `a.link_imagelibrary` cannot make use of a single call to either `getElementsByClassName()` or `getElementsByTagName()`, but in my test I did not include the class? Strange.

Answer (score 1):

You do like this:

```
if(url.indexOf('#hidden') > -1) alert('yes !')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat different answer. Are looking for the contents of a page at the url clicked?

Here is an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fFHhk/

```
var url = 'http://s.codepen.io'; // will look for a link pointing to this url
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('a[href="'+url+'"]').click(function(e) { // when clicked it will load the page

    $.get(url, function(data) {
      var doc = $(data);
      if (doc.has("#icon-heart").length) { // and check to see if there are any
        alert('yes!'); // elements with id icon-heart in it
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Hopefully you are not using this for spam!

Comment: nope. not spam. It's password protection for pdf download on shopify. Thanks for the answer!